# Android - Roboguice and Robolectric injecting activity members?

Tags: android, robolectric, roboguice

I am running JUnit tests using Robolectric. I am trying to test an Activity that has injected members. I am able to get my test class to Inject its own member correctly. But Still can't inject mocks into my Activity members.

I tried

```
@Inject LoginActivity loginActivity;
```

Also tried

```
LoginActivity activity = new LoginActivity();
injector.injectMembers(activity);
```

My Tests

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)

public class LoginActivityTest  {

    protected Injector injector;

        // This get injected correctly
        @Inject
        protected IServiceClient serviceClient;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(Robolectric.application, RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE, new MobileTestModule());
        injector = RoboGuice.getBaseApplicationInjector(Robolectric.application);
        injector.injectMembers(this);


        LoginActivity activity = new LoginActivity();
            // This fails
        injector.injectMembers(activity);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {

    }
```

My DI Module

```
public class MobileTestModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

        // Services
        bind(IServiceClient.class).toInstance(Mockito.mock(IServiceClient.class));
        // Other binding here
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the exception that I'm getting

```
com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for android.content.Context was bound.
  while locating android.content.Context
    for parameter 0 at com.company.app.helpers.SlideMenuAdapter.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating com.company.app.helpers.SlideMenuAdapter
    for field atcompanycom.company.atlasmobile.helpers.AtlasPhoneActivity.slideMenuAdapter(Unknown Source)
  while locating com.company.app.pages.login.LoginActivity
    for field at com.company.app.test.LoginActivityTest.loginActivity(Unknown Source)
  while locating com.company.app.test.LoginActivityTest

2) No scope is bound to roboguice.inject.ContextSingleton.
  at roboguice.inject.ContentViewListener.class(Unknown Source)
  while locating roboguice.inject.ContentViewListener
    for field at roboguice.activity.RoboActivity.ignored(Unknown Source)
  while locating com.nuvasive.atlasmobile.pages.login.LoginActivity
    for field at com.nuvasive.atlasmobile.test.LoginActivityTest.loginActivity(Unknown Source)
  while locating com.company.app.test.LoginActivityTest
```

Comment: Can you post the erorr you are seeing?

Comment: @Macro Updated my answer with the exceptions

Comment: It looks like you also inject a context. Maybe you need to add a context binding to your module?

Comment: Yes but haven't found how to bind the context. Been looking for this for the whole day. Tried binding Context to a mock context no luck

Comment: Ok fixed the context now it's complaining about layout inflator. So basically seems like Robolectric is not doing its job of using shadow classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you setup RoboGuice with Robolectric, and force injection on test class members.

```
// Setup Module
RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(Robolectric.application, RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE, Modules.override(RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(Robolectric.application)).with(new MyModule()));

// Get an Injector instance
injector = RoboGuice.getInjector(Robolectric.application);

// Inject properties on test class members (Marked with @Inject)
injector.injectMembers(this);
```

Here is how you initialize an activity when using Robolectric

```
LoginActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity.class).create().get();
```